# How to handle url path in web.py?

Tags: python, web, wsgi, web.py

I'm new to web.py, and use a lot of hardcoded url in my code for `href` in tag `a`,like
`/login`or`/?type=example`.

The problem is,
when I set my application running under a certain path, not the root of a URL, like
`http://example.com/appname/`

The link will direct me to some place like
`http://example.com/login`

While the expected/wanted one is
`http://example.com/appname/login`

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Make web.ctx.homepath available in your template globals, and output it before your paths.

From http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx

> homepath – The part of the path requested by the user which was
>   trimmed off the current app. That is homepath + path = the path
>   actually requested in HTTP by the user. E.g. /admin This seems to be
>   derived during startup from the environment variable REAL_SCRIPT_NAME.
>   It affects what web.url() will prepend to supplied urls. This in turn
>   affects where web.seeother() will go, which might interact badly with
>   your url rewriting scheme (e.g. mod_rewrite)

```
template_globals = {
    'app_path': lambda p: web.ctx.homepath + p,
}

render = template.render(my_template_dir, globals=template_globals, base="mylayout")
```

Then you should be able to output app_path in your templates

```
<a href="$app_path('/login')">Login</a>
```